# x-axis label in seqdplot

Tags: r, traminer

I have problems labelling my x-axis when I nplot the state-distribution by time points in sequence analysis using seqdplot() from the package TraMinR. The labelling works with other plotting functions like `seqiplot`. I can label the x-axis later with `title(xlab="")` however I don't know how this works when my sequences are grouped e.g. by gender. Am I missing something what makes the seqdplot function special? Thanks for your help!

Here is an example

```
library(TraMineR)

data(mvad)
mvad.labels <- c("employment", "further education", "higher education",
                 "joblessness", "school", "training")
mvad.scodes <- c("EM","FE","HE","JL","SC","TR")
mvad.seq <- seqdef(mvad, 15:86, states=mvad.scodes, labels=mvad.labels)

# Index plot: labelling works
seqiplot(mvad.seq, with.legend=F, xlab="time")

# State Distribution Plot: labelling doesn't work
seqdplot(mvad.seq, with.legend=F, xlab="time")
```

Comment: `title(xlab = "time")` works on `seqdplot()`. What is your expected outcome?

Comment: Yes it does work if you do it after using the `seqdplot` function. However `seqdplot(..., xlab="time")` should also works. It works e.g. with seqiplot.
Furthermore `title()` is very inconvenient when you group the plots e.g. by gender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a bug. The plot method `plot.stslist.statd` invoked by `seqdplot` ignored the `xlab` argument.

The bug has been fixed in the development version 2.3-1 available on [R-Forge](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=743). This development version will eventually become TraMineR 2.2.1 on the CRAN.

About the grouping mechanism: TraMineR uses `layout` to organize the groups. To use `title(xlab="time")` with grouping, you would have to create the grouped plot manually, which can be fastidious.